# Unable to openOrCreate database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```java
public class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    public ArrayList<String> groupItem, tempChild;
    public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public LayoutInflater minflater;
    Cursor cur;
    int requestCode = 1;
    int temp =18;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    int choice,hour,minute;
    TextView text = null;
    TextView text1 = null;
    public Activity activity;
    String server_ip="192.168.2.2";
    int server_port=14231;
    String messageStr="hc111";
    String op;
    public NewAdapter(ArrayList<String> grList, ArrayList<Object> childItem,
                    int choice,int hour,int minute,SQLiteDatabase db) {
        groupItem = grList;
        this.Childtem = childItem;
        this.choice = choice;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        //this.db = db;     
    }
    public void dbopen(){
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Daffy.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,
                null);
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        String create = "Create table if not exists AlarmTable(hour text," +
                    "minute text,hall text,device text,operation text)";
        db.execSQL(create);
    }
```

I created a class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter and trying to open the sqlite database and acces its functions.But I am not able to openOrCreateDatabase.
Why is openorcreatedatabase is not visible in a class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter.

Comment: I ask why is your code not visible... We're unable to help you.

Comment: error in openOrCreateDatabase function.

Comment: you cannot use openOrCreateDatabase in BaseExpandableListAdapter , you have to make seperate class for database where you need to define functions and construction to create and initialize your database

Comment: Please refer to this http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The [openOrCreateDatabase function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29) is a member of the `SQLiteDatabase` class.
It is not directly available in a class derived from `BaseExpandableListAdapter` because `BaseExpandableListAdapter` is not `SQLiteDatabase`.

Call it like this:

```java
db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(...);
```